# Safe/Secured room?

Tags: terminology, physical-access

I was involved in this project where development got outsourced to a consulting company, but to seal the deal the consulting company had to set up a room in their office with restricted access so that only consultants working on our projects could enter, and bunch of functions were disabled from workstations to prevent data leakage.

Is there a standard name for such a setup - would it be called a safe room or secured room or other ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no *standard* names for commercial rooms that just store sensitive information, but the ones you proposed seem reasonable. The two I most commonly come across are "sensitive area" and "restricted area". If you're feeling particularly blunt, "vault" will also do the job.

However, if the information is protectively marked (i.e. requires some form of clearance to view) then the correct term depends on the country. In the UK, it is referred to as a [LIST X room](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_X_site), and in the USA it's a [Sensitive Compartment Information Facility (SCIF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitive_Compartmented_Information_Facility). I believe both of these require inspection and sign-off from a governmental body in order to be officially recognised.

One term I do like is something I found in the USGS Physical Security Manual <sup>[[ref](http://www.usgs.gov/usgs-manual/handbook/hb/440-2-h/440-2-h-ch5.html)]</sup>, which refers to "controlled area" as somewhere that contains sensitive information (or is critical to your physical security model) but, by requirement, is also public access. This is useful terminology to know if you're partitioning out your building in terms of security procedure and requirements.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of valuable info. I think I will use 'restricted area', the description in USGS guide is in line with what we had setup.